# Simple product in bundle shoudl have a different price

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, bundle

I've configured several simple products in one bundle product. However I want the several simple product to appear in an own category and have a different prices as when configured in the bundle. Any tips?

Other workaround should be creating two products, one visible and one non-visible. But they should share their stock.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I've decided to add 'simple not-visible products' into my bundled product and create a second product which shares stock with the simple bundled product. It's only possible with a plugin because Magento wont shared stock.